# Casting inherited class in List of Superclass after Serialization

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, inheritance

I am currently developing an android game with a few classmates. It's an adaption of a board-game with cards and such. We have a server and a clientside, the communication works with Spring Boot.

I am facing a problem regarding the casting of elements of a list. We have a deck (ArrayList< Card>) and we have multiple types of cards, let's say bulletcards (with varying bullets left in the gun) and shootcards. BulletCard and ShootCard both inherit from Card.

If I add the cards to my ArrayList< Card>, I can cast them back to their inherited class with no problems on the serverside. But if the client get's the ArrayList, casting is not possible, because I loose the information of the subclass (the bulletcounter in the example).

Is there a way that I can also transfer this data?

```
ArrayList<Card> handcardDeck= new ArrayList<>();

handcardDeck.add(new ShootCard());
BulletCard bulletCard = new BulletCard();
bulletCard.setBulletCounter(3);
handcardDeck.add(bulletCard);

ShootCard s = (ShootCard) handcardDeck.get(0);
BulletCard b = (BulletCard) handcardDeck.get(1);
Integer i = b.getBulletCounter();
```

The Rest-Output looks like this:

```
 "cards": [
      {
        "id": 26
      },
      {
        "id": 28
      },
      {
        "id": 29
      },
      {
        "id": 32
      }
```

If I create a "pure" bulletsdeck (ArrayList< BulletCard>) I get this.

```
    "cards": [
      {
        "id": 17,
        "bulletCounter": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 18,
        "bulletCounter": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 19,
        "bulletCounter": 3
      }]
```

Can I somehow get the output of #2 for all Bulletcards in the list in #1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution:

Defining @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes in the parentclass did the trick.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo; 

@Entity
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(ShootCard.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(BulletCard.class)
})

public class Card implements Serializable {}
```

http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-Serialization-polymorphism.jsp